# How to add a tooltip to a d3.js path?

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, tooltip

I am building a floormap from geojson data using d3.js topo and d3.js path. For clarification, I am also using vue.js. I want to add a tooltip when the user hovers over a room (aka the d3.js path). First I added just a console log to when the user hovers over a path but that did not work. I noticed that every time I load the app it does a console log but not when a user clicks / hovers over the d3.js path. I heard someone say that I would have to create an invisible circle or rectangle which would have the tooltip property bind to it but I don't think that route would work once the floor maps get complex. I dont care about adding any actual data to the tooltip right now but later I would want to.  Can someone point me in the right direction, please? Thank you.

```js
const data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              0, 0
            ],
            [
              0, 11.4
            ],
            [
              7, 11.4
            ],
            [
              7, 0
            ],
            [
              0, 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              7, 0
            ],
            [
              7, 11.4
            ],
            [
              12, 11.4
            ],
            [
              12, 0
            ],
            [
              7, 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              12, 0
            ],
            [
              12, 11.4
            ],
            [
              19, 11.4
            ],
            [
              19, 0
            ],
            [
              12, 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var width = +svg.attr("width")
var height = +svg.attr("height")

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)")

var projection = d3.geoIdentity().fitSize([width, height], data)
var path = d3.geoPath(projection)

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("fill", "grey")
  .attr("fill-opacity", .2)
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .on("mouseover", console.log("hello"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="200"></svg>
```

Comment: Please make sure the example is runnable. Especially now, we have no idea whether your path describes the entire room, or just traces the walls. Please add some sample data, even if it is just one room. Also, `.on("mouseover", function() { console.log("Hello"); })` should work better. What you did was not pass a *function* as an argument, but the *result* of a function.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot I added some sample data. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The simplest - but most limited - one is to create a [`<title>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title) in each `path`. It will show on hover, as it's browser native.

```js
const data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "name": "Kitchen" },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              0, 0
            ],
            [
              0, 11.4
            ],
            [
              7, 11.4
            ],
            [
              7, 0
            ],
            [
              0, 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "name": "Living room" },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              7, 0
            ],
            [
              7, 11.4
            ],
            [
              12, 11.4
            ],
            [
              12, 0
            ],
            [
              7, 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "name": "Toilet" },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              12, 0
            ],
            [
              12, 11.4
            ],
            [
              19, 11.4
            ],
            [
              19, 0
            ],
            [
              12, 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var width = +svg.attr("width")
var height = +svg.attr("height")

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)")

var projection = d3.geoIdentity().fitSize([width, height], data)
var path = d3.geoPath(projection)

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("fill", "grey")
  .attr("fill-opacity", .2)
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .append("title")
  // Do this to maintain access to the features you drew
  .datum(function(d) { return d; })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.properties.name;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="200"></svg>
```

More complicated ones can use an absolutely positioned `div`, for example:

```js
const data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Kitchen"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              0, 0
            ],
            [
              0, 11.4
            ],
            [
              7, 11.4
            ],
            [
              7, 0
            ],
            [
              0, 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Living room"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              7, 0
            ],
            [
              7, 11.4
            ],
            [
              12, 11.4
            ],
            [
              12, 0
            ],
            [
              7, 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Toilet"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              12, 0
            ],
            [
              12, 11.4
            ],
            [
              19, 11.4
            ],
            [
              19, 0
            ],
            [
              12, 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var width = +svg.attr("width")
var height = +svg.attr("height")
var tooltip = d3.select("#tooltip")

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)")

var projection = d3.geoIdentity().fitSize([width, height], data)
var path = d3.geoPath(projection)

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("fill", "grey")
  .attr("fill-opacity", .2)
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    // +3 as some offset to make sure spawning the tooltip doesn't
    // accidentally also cause unhover and thus removing itself
    tooltip
      .html(d.properties.name)
      .style("display", "block")
      .style("left", d3.event.x + 3 + 'px')
      .style("top", d3.event.y + 3 + 'px');
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function() {
    tooltip
      .style("display", null)
      .style("left", null)
      .style("top", null);
  });
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="200"></svg>
<div id="tooltip"></div>
```